# Initializing RecyclerView and Adapter in onCreateView, but getting error "No adapter attached; skipping layout"

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am getting the error "No adapter attached; skipping layout" when using RecyclerView. I looked at so many answers on Stack Overflow, but they all seemed to say that the RecyclerView and Adapter must be initialized. I am doing this, but still getting this error. Does anyone see why?

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

private EditText ipText;
private VncDatabase database;
private GridLayoutManager lLayout;

private ButtonCreator bc;
RecyclerViewAdapter rcAdapter;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    List<ItemObject> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    rcAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),myList);


}

// onCreateView
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);


    // Get screen to determine number of rows
    // see src/main/res/values/integers.xml
    int columnCount = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.grid_column_count);
    lLayout = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), columnCount,
            GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

    RecyclerView rView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    rView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rView.setLayoutManager(lLayout);
    rView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);


    return view;
}



public void createButton (Drawable d, String appName){

    Log.d("tag_name", "Make sure createButton is called");
    rcAdapter.addItem(new ItemObject(appName, d));

}



// In order to get the view of HomeFragment correctly

public interface ButtonCreator{
    void buttonCreator(Drawable d, String string);
}



@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    bc = (ButtonCreator) activity;
}


}
```

My drawable and string are getting passed from a different activity that calls "createButton" method, which adds an Image button to my GridLayout.

Comment: AFAICT, that message is benign and can be ignored. It is not a crash.